# Is there a way to do cascading persist programmatically in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I understand that it is possible to do so via annotations in the persistent class, but is there a way to achieve the same using the API? For instance passing an argument to `saveOrUpdate` to tell the session to persist the object transitively?